# Como agregar un insert para guardar el nombre de las imagenes en mi base de datos mysql

Tags: php, mysqli

Deseo obtener el nombre de cada una de las imágenes subidas al servidor web y guardarlas en mi base de datos para luego consultarlas.
 a ver si alguien me echa una mano.

Gracias por su ayuda

### Aqui dejo el script que utilizo para subir las imágenes

foreach($_FILES['files']['name'] as $i => $name) {

```
$name = $_FILES['files']['name'][$i];
$size = $_FILES['files']['size'][$i];
$type = $_FILES['files']['type'][$i];
$tmp = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$i];

$explode = explode('.', $name);

$ext = end($explode);

$path = 'uploads/';
$path = $path . basename( $explode[0] . time() .'.'. $ext);

$errors = array();

if(empty($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$i])) {
    $errors[] = 'Please choose at least 1 file to be uploaded.';
}else {

    $allowed = array('jpg','jpeg','gif','bmp','png');

    $max_size = 4000000; // 4MB

    if(in_array($ext, $allowed) === false) {
        $errors[] = 'The file <b>'.$name.'</b> extension is not allowed.';
    }

    if($size > $max_size) {
        $errors[] = 'The file <b>'.$name.'</b> size is too hight.';
    }

}

if(empty($errors)) {

    if(!file_exists('uploads')) {
        mkdir('uploads', 0777);
    }

    if(move_uploaded_file($tmp, $path)) {
        echo '<p>The file <b>'.$name.'</b> successfully uploaded</p>';
    }else {
        echo 'Something went wrong while uploading the file <b>'.$name.'</b>';
    }

}else {
    foreach($errors as $error) {
        echo '<p>'.$error.'<p>';
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dado que no brindas información adicional de cómo realizas la conexión ni de la tabla en la que deseas guardar los datos, te daré un ejemplo genérico de cómo insertar en base de datos usando las funciones puras de php.

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "INSERT INTO MyGuests (firstname, lastname, email)
VALUES ('John', 'Doe', 'john@example.com')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
```

Este código lo puedes poner en una función y llamarla cuando la subida del archivo sea exitosa. El nombre del archivo ya lo tienes en la variable que en tu script se llama `$name`

Dejó la [referencia](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp) por si deseas ampliar

Saludos.

Comment: Gracias por responder.
el codigo que me has sugerido funciona genial para insertar una imagen pero en el script que mande arriba vienen todas las imágenes juntas en un array.
para que funcione habría que recorrer el array para sacar los nombres de las imagenes 1 por 1 y es lo que no se hacer..